Chart:- Property access must assign to the property or use its value
I'm using Visual Basic 2019 in Visual Studio. I am wanting to use the chart control. The chart control appears in the Toolbox and I can load the default chart to a form without problems. Whenever I code with "Chart1.ChartAreas" or "Chart1.Series", I get the wavy red line under this pair of the statement indicating an error. I have been unable to solve this issue. When I move the mouse pointer over, A message says, "ReadOnly Property.Datavisualization.Charting. ..." For potential fixes, the Alt-Enter and Ctrl + give different suggestions. These sugggestions I've found to be vague and useless.
Is there an incorrect setting in the options? (Tools - Options) Do I need to stop it being Read only? How can I get it to work? While googling "Property access must assign to the property value or use its value" it is apparent this causes considerable grief.Thanks, David.
Ive tried "Dim Chart1 as Chart".-> "Chart type is not defined."
I found the microsoft web page to be vague and unhelpful.
I've looked at "Systems.Windows.Forms.Datavisualization" which is a property list. Several are "Public ReadOnly Property {name} As ... Will deleting the "ReadOnly" work?
